# Вывод изображения с помощью php в html

Tags: php, html

Имеется множество html-страниц. С помощью скрипта на php вывожу в браузер содержимое html-страницы.

```
$str = file_get_contents("first.html");
echo str_replace(array("<html>", "</html>", "<body>", "</body>"), "", $str);
```

При этом если html содержит картинку, она не выводится. Картинки находятся в папке images. 
Как сделать проверку на наличие в html картинки и если картинка есть, выводить картинку там, где в html прописан соответствующий тег (img src...).

**Добавлено из комментария**.

Делал вот так:

```
$dir = "./images/";
$opdir = opendir($dir);

while ($file = readdir($opdir))
{
    if($file == ".." || $file == ".")
    continue;
    $w = explode("-", $file);
    $el = $dir."el-".$word[1];

    echo "<img src=\"".$el."\" hspace=30px vspace=20px></a>";
}

closedir($opdir);
```

В итоге на html странице там где должна быть картинка - просто рамка.

Comment: regexp да и пути можно проверить, вдруг неправильно картинки относительно исполняемого файла лежат.

Comment: а можно конкретнее?

Comment: это называется - давайте придумаем себе головную боль!

Comment: mojno skanirovat direktoriyu i vivesti. tipo opendir readdir. neznayu pomojet li eto ili net.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.